# mysql inner join condition to ignore duplicate ids

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sum, inner-join

### Given below the list of tables.

**Order the shop ids in the descending order based on the sum of number of clicks for a product in the locations [23,24,25,26,27].**

> Given product_id = 8

---

link_shops_locations

```
shop_id | location_id
---------------------
1       | 23
2       | 24
3       | 25
3       | 26
3       | 27
```

---

products_clicks

```
shop_id | product_id | clicks
-----------------------------
1       | 8          | 1
2       | 7          | 3
2       | 8          | 87
3       | 8          | 21
3       | 8          | 9
```

---

link_products_shops

```
product_id | shop_id
---------------------
 7         | 1
 8         | 1
 8         | 1
 8         | 2
 8         | 2
 8         | 1
 7         | 3
 8         | 3
```

This is what I have tried,

```
SELECT SUM(c.clicks) as no,
       s.shop_id
FROM  link_products_shops l
INNER JOIN products_clicks c
ON c.product_id = l.product_id
INNER JOIN link_shops_locations s
ON s.shop_id = c.shop_id // duplicate shop_ids gives wrong SUM
WHERE s.location_id IN (23,24,25,26,27)
GROUP BY s.shop_id
ORDER BY no DESC;
```

**My problem is, since the link_shops_locations table has 3 shop_ids, the resulting expected SUM is multiplied by 3. How do I solve this?** The INNER JOIN condition of link_shops_locations has something to do with this?. A little help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

[1]You missed one more condition in **INNER JOIN with products_clicks**.

[2]Also you ignored `product_id`. Have a look at this query.

[3]You had inserted `product_id=8 and shop_id=1` three times in `link_products_shops` table.

```
    select shop_id, SUM(NoOfClicks) FROM(SELECT distinct c.shop_id, c.clicks AS NoOfClicks 
FROM  products_clicks c 
INNER JOIN link_products_shops l 
ON c.product_id = l.product_id 
AND c.shop_id = l.shop_id 
INNER JOIN link_shops_locations s 
ON s.shop_id = c.shop_id and s.shop_id = l.shop_id 
WHERE s.location_id IN (23,24,25,26,27) 
AND c.product_id = 8) AS TabShopCounters
GROUP BY shop_id
ORDER BY NoOfClicks DESC;
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22fe/8

Comment: ok i missed that. I got it now. But still, my question is for the lcoations 25,26,27 there will be duplicate shop_ids which is 3. Because this, the resulting SUM(clicks) is multiplied into 3. How to make it unique?.

Comment: Why you have duplicate rows in `link_products_shops`. Remove them and check. Updated my query and answer with fiddle